# (Python) Upload a file via 'Browse' window Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, automation

For testing purposes, I need to

1. Choose a file via the Browse window ([See screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQ1lS.png))
2. Click on 'Open' (to upload the file to the website) and then
3. Click on "Upload".

How do I do that via selenium? 'cause the following did not work:

```
# hident2 is the name of "Choose File" element
wd.find_element(By.XPATH("//input[@id='hident2']")).sendKeys("C:\\Users\\file-to-upload.xml"); 

# input.btn.primary is the name of "Upload" button element**
wd.find_element_by_css_selector("input.btn.primary").click()
```

I get the following error:

> TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using the `find_element()` method correctly. Pass the `By.XPATH` as a separate argument:

```
wd.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@id='hident2']")
```

Or, use the direct shortcut:

```
wd.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='hident2']")
```

Or, just use the "by id" built-in locator:

```
wd.find_element_by_id("hident2")
```

Also, the method is called `send_keys()` and not `sendKeys()`.

Comment: So I changed the line to:     wd.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='hident2']").sendKeys("C:\\Users\\NAVEH\\PycharmProjects\\SuiteShare Sanity Tests\\subject-scheme.xml"); as you said an now I am getting the following error: AttributeError: 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'sendKeys'

Comment: @NavehMadmon ah, sure, this is the second issue, use `send_keys()` instead.